# How to enable blkmq for NVMe devices?

Tags: nvme, io, scheduler

Ubuntu: 20.10-desktop
kernel: 5.8.0-40-generic
Device: Samsung 980 pro 500G

```bsh
$ cat /sys/block/nvme1n1/queue/scheduler
  [none] mq-deadline
```

Does it means I am using the "Linux I/O scheduler" rather than the "Linux Multi-Queue Block IO Queueing Mechanism (blk-mq)". If yes, how can I switch to blkmq?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Version attached. Thanks @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel will be using blk-mq for such a device already. You can even tell because you have only the multi queue deadline scheduler!

(The following information was found via the search https://www.google.com/search?q=blk-mq+nvme )

Per this [answer on How to disable blk-mq for NVMe and use CFQ, deadline, noop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428171/109111) you can't actually switch NVMe drives to use anything but blk-mq since the 3.19 kernel (see the commit [NVMe: Convert to blk-mq](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a4aea5623d4a54682b6ff5c18196d7802f3e478f)) and prior to that the multi queue logic was inside the NVMe driver itself anyway.